# JMeter won't write response data

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, jmeter, error-logging

I'm running tests with JMeter (master+10 slaves) on elasticasearch. I'm getting error 400 for some requests but they are a bit elusive:

- When I run the requests manually with curl or pasting them on kibana's console, I don't get errors.
- Every time I run the tests using jmeter, using the same requests and under the same conditions, I get a different number of errors.

So I was thinking of inspecting the response bodies from jmeter. But all the ways I've tried failed:

- I've created a View Result Tree element and checked all boxes on the "configure" panel. When I run the script, it logs everything **except** response data
- I've tried a BeanShell post processor to write all responses on a file. But it apparently is being 'ignored' when I run the script

Both these solutions work on my machine, but not on the server (which I don't have total control over). I'm passing jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true on the command line to start jmeter.

What else could I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an optimization that JMeter makes for distributed testing related to the mode:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote_batching_config

To avoid JMeter stripping the response data set in user.properties of servers snd controller:

> mode=Batch

As by default it is:

> mode=StrippedBatch

Comment: How to set Mode = Batch in Jmeter. Please share the any corresponding links

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter slaves don't send response data to the master, you can [choose a different sample sender](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode) if you need more data.

Writing response data into a file using Beanshell should work in any case (however [consider using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for this), just make sure that:

- your Beanshell PostProcessor is placed correctly according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
- there are no Beanshell-related messages in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) files
- you will need to collect the log files from each slave manually after test run, they will not be generated on the master